# How do I copy a range of cells relative to my active cell?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, offset

I am trying to write macro that selects a range of cells relative to my active cell and copies all the cells that are selected.

Currently the code I have selects these cells but doesn't copy them.

```
Sub CellCopy()
ActiveCell.Offset(0).Resize(5, 8).Select
ActiveCell.Copy
End Sub
```

Thanks, sorry for the very begginer post.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(0).Resize(5, 8).Copy` but you have to Paste somewhere.

Comment: When you step through your code via `F8` function key, does your spreadsheet show the "marching ants" moving dashed lines?

Comment: Not sure if it is do-able for this case but I recommend reading on: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
    Activecell.Copy
```

You need to use

```
   Selection.Copy
```